# Filter with loop for Several Dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following question on using Filter with Loop.

I have several Delivery Dates and a Masterdata of Inventory.  I want to display the inventory one day before the delivery date (Column A590). And this has to be done  for several dates till the end of the year.  I have the basic code for filtering the delivery till the day before the delivery date. But it displays nothing. and I dont know how to put into a loop for consequent days, so that It calculates inventory one day before each delivery date.

```
Sub DT_Filter()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$585").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & Range("A590")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates in Excel & VBA are a bit complicated - [MSDN Date Systems in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel). The way you have written the sample, it compares text. Thus, try to convert to a number for a better comparison:

```
Sub DT_Filter()
    Range("A3:A10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & CLng(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Thus, if you make a small sample like this one:

[image]

You will be able to filter 09-March and 03-March after running the code above like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please see the Code below,                                                       
Sub Filter_RPCALC()
ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$585").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Range("A590"))

Range("N2").Formula = "=DAYS($A$590,D2)"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(x1Down)).Select , Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub

Comment: @sheela - Did you copy this code from a cheap VBA book? `x1Down` should be `xlDown`...

Comment: No. From Online. Actually I am beginner in vba excel. However I didnt use the code above. But  I have one more query. May be I will post it as a new question.

Comment: @sheela - where is the online source, where there is `x1Down`? I have noticed a few of similar questions, I thought it was some bad book actually. And yup, a new question is a good idea.